# Hide drawer navigation header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to hide Drawer Header on react native application. Currently,using `react-navigation ^1.5.12`.
* I want to delete grey header

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyVFh.png)

My code look like this.
Router.js

```
const HomeStack = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Message: { screen: Message },
  History: { screen: History },
  Settings: { screen: Settings },
}, {
  contentComponent: DrawerMenu,
  drawerWidth: 240,
  // Explicitly set the default screen to use
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

export default const MainStack = StackNavigator({
  LoggedInHome: { screen: HomeStack },
  Notification: { screen: Notification },
}, {
  // Explicitly set the default screen to use
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});
```

I added `header: null` on each screen also.

DrawerMenu.js

```
export default class DrawerMenu extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }

  navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Home', { isStatusBarHidden: false })}
        >
          <Text>Home</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
...
```

Comment: can you show the code please, or you can check navigation code as :- main entry file https://github.com/prince-verma/react-native-template-basic/blob/master/src/scenes/routes.js ,   drawer navigator https://github.com/prince-verma/react-native-template-basic/blob/master/src/scenes/drawer/drawer.js, hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks Prince, I really appreciate that. But that would not work. My code is Router JS and Drawer JS.

Comment: I mis the Test view profile (The green block) in you code example. Can you show where you got that in you code?

Comment: Prince, Perry thanks for your advise. Here is my code. https://github.com/ShunYamada/nativeMap

Comment: @ShunYamada I can't find the drawer options like you have in you image. Also you project does not contain the tekst view profile. Can you check if you pushed everything? Or just point me to the right file that contains that stuff.

Comment: Thanks Perry, here is drawer menu https://github.com/ShunYamada/nativeMap/blob/master/src/components/common/DrawerMenu.js on my repo. Drawer Button is here https://github.com/ShunYamada/nativeMap/blob/master/src/components/common/DrawerButton.js And you can tap <DrawerButton /> on this AnimatedView https://github.com/ShunYamada/nativeMap/blob/master/src/components/AnimatedView.js

Answer (score 0):

you should try it like this:

```
  Home: {
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  header: null,
}),
```

Comment: why wouldnt it work? i have a pretty similar constelation and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You should set the navigation options in your drawer's instantiation :

```
const HomeStack = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
  },
  ...
```